# If a user who voted on a deleted answer was removed, I get a wrong reputation alert

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications, deleted-answers, deleted-accounts

The following things happened:

- A few months ago I posted [an answer on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/23371/16889) (10 k only).
- That answer received thirtysomething upvotes (and got me [this badge](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=16889).
- A few days later that answer was deleted and all the reputation I gained from it was voided.
- Since I had no other answers or comments, my reputation went back to 101 ([here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/16889/wrzlprmft) is my reputation-, question- and answerless account).
- Yesterday, I received a top-bar reputation notification for −10 with reason “User was removed” on Skeptics. My reputation stayed at 101, however. Since I did not actually lose any reputation, I consider that reputation notification a bug.

I can only guess that the last event was caused by the removal of some user who had voted on my deleted answer.

Comment: If the answer was deleted X days after being upvoted, you don't lose reputation when the answer is deleted. I don't recall how much is those X days, but there is a post somewhere here.

Comment: See [Reputation and Historical Archives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). It says the post needs to have a score of at least 3, and be visible for at least 60 days. If that is not the case, then it is a bug; otherwise, it is the expected behavior.

Comment: I am aware of all this, but this is not about losing reputation from the answer but about getting incorrectly notified of a reputation loss which did not happen. Moreover, the answer in question did not last 60 days and all reputation I gained from it (more than 300) was revoked.